# Canvas not suppported in WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to animate a canvas in WPF using `Storyboard` and `DoubleAnimationsUsingKeyFrames` my code goes something like this:

```
<Canvas x:Name="bgCanvas" Height="261" Canvas.Top="-262" Width="720">
            <Canvas.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/backgroundBlurred.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            </Canvas.Background>
            <Canvas.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="bgAnim" x:Name="bgAnim">
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(bgCanvas.Opacity)" Storyboard.Target="bgCanvas">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="1.5" Value="1"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </Canvas.Resources>
```

I'm also using Mahapps.Metro for the project. `<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(bgCanvas.Opacity)" Storyboard.Target="bgCanvas">` is underlined by blue lines and the error reads: 
`bgCanvas is not supported in a Windows Presentation Format (WPF) Application.`

I'm not sure whats wrong with the code.

BONUS: Is this the right way to animate a canvas in WPF?

Sorry for the nub questions.

Comment: How are you going to start the Storyboard?

Comment: @Clemens Umm. I'm thinking about a function (which triggers the storyboard) which gets invoked by the construct of my `MainWindow` class. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start the animation in an `EventTrigger` on the `Loaded` event of the Canvas:

```
<Canvas ...>
    <Canvas.Background>
        <ImageBrush .../>
    </Canvas.Background>
    <Canvas.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="1"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Canvas.Triggers>
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `(bgCanvas.Opacity)` with `(Canvas.Opacity)`

Comment: Or better just with `Opacity`.

Comment: When I try `Opacity` or `Canvas.Opacity` the `Storyboard.Target="bgCanvas"` gets underlined showing error: `The TypeConverter for 'Dependency Object' does not support converting from a string.` Any ideas??

Comment: Problem fixed by using `Storyboard.TargetName` instead. Thanks!